# Can't spawn child process

Tags: node.js

I wrote a simple function that restarts/shuts down application. Restart doesn't work and i can't figure out why. Child process starts and then instantly shuts down. I tried catching errors from the child but there was no errors.

```
async function Shutdown(message,restart){
    if(message) console.log(message)

    await Logout()

    if(restart){
        let proc = childprocess.spawn(process.argv[0],process.argv.splice(1),{
            "detached": true,
        })
    }
    process.exit(0)
}
```

Comment: i believe `process.exit(0)` makes it shutdown without errors, produce more output with `console.log`, also look into something like https://github.com/Unitech/pm2 to manage your processes.

Comment: i tried to check child's exit code but it exits with 0
proc.on('exit',function(code){console.log(code)})

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_options_detached):

> When using the detached option to start a long-running process, the
>   process will not stay running in the background after the parent exits
>   unless it is provided with a stdio configuration that is not connected
>   to the parent.

So add `stdio: 'ignore'` or other methods to make child process stays alive

```
    let proc = childprocess.spawn(process.argv[0],process.argv.splice(1),{
          detached: true,
          stdio: 'ignore'
    })
   proc.unref();
```

Comment: I tried it and child process still shuts down instantly.